# Publish Lightswitch application freeze visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, lightswitch-2013

I want to publish a Lightswitch HTML client application to a Azure web app. The problem is after clicking "Publish" visual studio 2013 freeze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that I use multiple azure subscriptions in Visual Studio and the Lightswitch Publish dialog is not able to handle multiple azure subscriptions.

Solution:

- Go to Visual Studio -> Server Explorer
- Right-click to Azure -> Manage subscriptions
- Select only the required azure subscription
- Publish

Comment: Thanks alot, I spend hours trying to figure out what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with multiple subscriptions. When the problem could not be fixed by managing subscriptions I ended up closing Visual Studio and deleting the **Windows Azure Subscription.XLM** file found at C:\Users*xxxx*\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings on my computer.  The next time you publish you will need to re-enter your subscription credentials.  Hope this helps.